# X Server config used by lightdm

Tags: xorg, lightdm, opengl, xserver

What I want to do is to start a x server just like the lightdm did.
But I can't get the X server perform just like the one started by lightdm.

I see the X server process executed by lightdm is:

```
root      4984  4978  4 19:57 tty7     00:00:48 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

When I stop the lightdm and used the command above to start an X server, it works, but I feel something different, the performance and some advanced support.

For example, using the X server I started, I may get some errors when running Android emulator with GPU support:

1. Create pbuffer failed. (this error also arise when I use Xvfb)
2. CreateGraphicBuffer failed.(Something like that, I get this error from the adb logcat.)

While all these errors never arise when I using the lightdm(the ubuntu GUI).

Can someone tell me the different of the configs used by X server which started by the lightdm and the one I started manually.

PS: 
I also used the config file generated by:

```
sudo X -configure
```

But it seem more like the X server I start without a config file.
And I don't know how to modify the config file so that the X server can perform the same in the lightdm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

From here :)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM